# How can I use a Chrome extension in a Selenium Tests with BrowserStack?

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, browserstack

I am trying to test AdBlock Chrome Extension on BrowserStack's Chrome browser. However, I am not able to do so.

Please help with this.

I tried this on my local Chrome browser and it is working as expected

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "ChromeOptions" class to add Chrome extension in your Selenium tests both locally and on BrowserStack.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("<path to extension directory>.crx"));
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

You can refer to [Add Extensions on Remote Browsers](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/add-plugins-extensions-remote-browsers) article on BrowserStack